# Code hangs up on return statement

Tags: python, return, pydev, sha1

I'm having an issue with some python test code for a SHA1 algorithm that I can't figure out. It seems like the code is hanging up on a return statement, as best I can tell, but I can't figure why that would be.

```
def testMakeWords():
   msg = Message(0xff00ff00800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020)
   msg.padded_message = 0xff00ff00800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
   word_list = msg.packageWords()
   print("Returned:", word_list)
   print("Expected: [ff00ff00, 80000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000020]")

class Message():

    def __init__(self, message, length=None):

        self.raw_input = message
        self.workingValue = message
        self.initialLength = self.__sanitizeLength__(length)
        self.padded_message = []
        self.word_list = []
        self.messageBlocks = []
        self.initial_hash = [0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476, 0xc3d2e1f0]

    """takes a message, and packages it into a list of words."""
    def packageWords(self):
        wordSize = 32
        binaryMessage = bin(self.padded_message)[2:]
        wordList = []
        startIndex = 0
        endIndex = wordSize

        for k in range(0, len(binaryMessage), wordSize):
            print("Indecies: {} -- {}".format(startIndex, endIndex))
            wordValue = int(binaryMessage[startIndex:endIndex], 2)
            newWord = Word32(wordValue)
            wordList.append(newWord)
            startIndex = startIndex + wordSize
            endIndex = endIndex + wordSize

        self.word_list = wordList
        print("blah blah blah")
        return wordList

class Word32(Word):

    def __init__(self, value):

        self.wordSize = 32
        self.value = self.__checkValue__(value)
        """internal method, checks that the value given to a word is not larger than the size of that word."""
    def __checkValue__(self, value):

        if len(bin(value)[2:]) > self.wordSize:
            print("ERROR: word value greater than word length")
            return
        return value

    def __repr__(self):

        binString = bin(self.value)[2:]
        while (len(binString) < self.wordSize / 4):
            hexString = "0" + binString
        binString = binString
        return binString
```

For simplicity I just included the method where the code is hanging up. All of the code in the `packageWords` method prints, when I run the code, but the 2 print statements after the `packageWords` call do not print. The code shows as still running, but nothing is happening.

I'm at a loss for what's going on here.

- I added some of the word class I'm using, minus some of the functions such as rotate that don't effect this problem.

Comment: Well if it prints "blah blah blah" then the only possible thing that could be making your program hang is the `__str__` method of `Word32`.

Comment: Yah, it would be helpful to know how `Word32` is defined.

Comment: [PDB](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is your friend. Run your script, set a breakpoint just before you think the bad return is happening, and step through it. That will get you an answer even faster than SO can.

Comment: I don't really understand how `__str__` would create a problem here, I've been able to print in the past with my repr method, but `__str__` is currently at default for Object. I've tested printing already. I added some of the `Word32` class that's relevant to this problem. Thanks

Comment: Is the indentation and code correct for the __repr__ method - it looks like it is an infinite loop - as binString doesn't change, and therefore neither term in your while condition will either.

Comment: Bear in mind that unless you have explicitly defined __str__ then __str__ will use __repr__. Have you defined __str__ on word ?

Comment: I have not defined str, just repr, that's how I wastaught to do a printable object. I'm not sure I really understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined an infinite loop in your `Word32.__repr__` method. The error relates to these lines:

```
    while (len(binString) < self.wordSize / 4):
        hexString = "0" + binString
```

You have a loop with a stopping condition that the length of `binString` must be equal to or greater than `self.wordSize / 4`. The body of the loop does not alter the length of `binString` at all, and subsequently the loop will never stop.

If you change that to:

```
    while (len(binString) < self.wordSize / 4):
        binString = "0" + binString
```

Then your loop will eventually stop.

In general you may want to think more and code less, because lines like:

```
    binString = binString
```

Indicate to me that you are just trying things until something works, rather than trying to understand the problem and then devise an appropriate solution. Good luck!